# Are there examples of nondegenerate Fermi gases?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, fermi-liquids

A degenerate Fermi gas is an ensemble of fermions with very low interactions and at temperatures that are low enough (lower than Fermi temperature). Most of the examples in the literature are about this kind of systems (electrons in metals, white dwarfs, neutron stars). Is there an example of non-degenerate Fermi gases? Wouldn't a high temperature Fermi gas just behave as an ideal classical gas, why then keep the label degenerate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an example of non-degenerate Fermi gases?

Yes, of course. A non-degenerate Fermi or Bose gas just behaves like a classical gas. Approximately half of all gases you know about, at typical atmospheric pressure, are really Fermi gases, and the other half are Bose. Off the top of my head $\text{NH}_3$ is Fermi, for instance.

> Wouldn't a high temperature Fermi gas just behave as an ideal classical gas, why then keep the label degenerate?

Classical is just the same thing as nondegenerate, and nondegenerate means $\langle n \rangle \ll 1$ where $n$ is the typical state occupancy. It's not the same thing as high temperature. For example, a photon gas in a box never stops being a degenerate Bose gas no matter how hot it gets, because more and more photons are produced as the temperature rises.